# How can I add an extended Git commit message in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-commit

I use Visual Studio Code as my IDE. When I make a Git commit, I can only enter the commit message (subject line). Where can I write in the commit body or the extended commit message?

Answer (score 0):

In the commit message input (that shows as long as you don't hide it with `"git.showCommitInput": false,`), you can press <kbd>enter</kbd> to enter newline characters. (press twice after the end of the subject line, since blocks of text in git commit messages are separated by empty lines)

If you're concerned about line lengths, see the following settings (shown with their default values):

```json
"git.inputValidation": "warn",
"git.inputValidationLength": 72,
"git.inputValidationSubjectLength": 50,
```

You can also use the editor mode for writing commit messages, which you can do by pressing the commit button with an empty commit message input. When you're done writing there, save and close that editor tab.